# Need to bind list data by row in R

Tags: r, list, rbind

I have a problem in binding list by row in R.
My list data set is:

```
id:1
data$k: 1
id k b c
1 1 1 3
----------------
data$k: 2
id k b c
1 2 1 4
--------------
id:2
data$k: 1
id k b c
2 1 1 6
----------------
data$k: 2
id k b c
2 2 5 10
```

And I want is:

```
id k b c
1 1 1 3
1 2 1 4
2 1 1 6
2 2 5 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(yourlist)` should do the job

Answer (score 9):

You can use `do.call(rbind,data)` for that

Alternative:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(data)
```

Comment: I get something like:  do.call("rbind",l)
     5      6      7     
[1,] List,5 List,3 List,6

Comment: can you please post the sample data, using `dput`?

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package offers a function called `rbindlist`. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Using purrr:

```
purrr::map_df(list_of_data_frames,~ .x)
```