# Is there a way to unlist elements according to the elements of the list and then create a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists

I want to unlist a variable and then convert it to a data frame. The variable has this structure:

```
> str(socialmedia$social_network_accounts, list.len = 3)
List of 2767
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ type : chr [1:2] "Twitter" "YouTube"
  ..$ value: chr [1:2] "https://www.twitter.com/MarinadelPilar" "https://www.youtube.com/c/MarinadelPilar"
```

I've tried this code:

```
(SMedia <- tibble(Redes = socialmedia$social_network_accounts))
```

And I got this

```
# A tibble: 2,767 x 1
   Redes       
   <list>      
 1 <df [2 × 2]>
 2 <df [0 × 0]>
 3 <df [1 × 2]>
 4 <df [1 × 2]>
 5 <df [1 × 2]>
 6 <df [0 × 0]>
 7 <df [0 × 0]>
 8 <df [2 × 2]>
 9 <df [2 × 2]>
10 <df [1 × 2]>
# … with 2,757 more rows

names(SMedia$Redes[[1]])
[1] "type"  "value"
```

Then I tried to create a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(SMedia$Redes),nrow = 3050))
```

But I obtained this output in the same column

```
matrix.unlist.SMedia.Redes...nrow...3050.
Twitter
YouTube
https://www.twitter.com/MarinadelPilar
https://www.youtube.com/c/MarinadelPilar
Twitter
https://www.twitter.com/LupJonesof
```

So, I want to have a column for "type" and another for "value" in a data frame, because I want to calculate some statistics.

I'd appreciate your help,

Osiris

Comment: Do you mean `do.call("rbind", socialmedia)`?

Comment: May be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258953/need-to-bind-list-data-by-row-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a sample data would be easier, but if I understand correctly, you have a list of dataframes called `socialmedia$social_network_accounts` and you want to put them together. In that case, something like

```
purrr::map_df(socialmedia$social_network_accounts,~ .x)
```

shoud work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `rbindlist`

```
data.table::rbindlist(SMedia$Redes)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(SMedia, Redes)
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example? I can't get it working, it keeps telling me that `unnest` expects a data.frame.

Comment: I was just curious to know how could it work. I was trying to use unnest with a list similar to the one in the question: 
`l1 <- list(data.frame(x = "q",y = "w"),data.frame(x = "a",y = "b"))
tidyr::unnest(l1)`

Comment: @xaviescacs you are directly using on a list.  Insteda it would be `tibble(col1 = l1) %>% unnest(col1)`

Comment: That is nice indeed. May I suggest that you could improve your answer by specifying that Redes is a list on a SMedia data.frame.